# What's the translation of switcheroo in French?

Tags: traduction

A switcheroo [is a](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switcheroo):

> sudden unexpected variation or reversal, often for a humorous purpose. It is colloquially used in reference to an act of intentionally or unintentionally swapping two objects.

What's the translation of *switcheroo* in French? Google Translate and DeepL didn't help.

Comment: [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/switcheroo) defines it as *échange, changement inattendu,* which isn't so different from Wiktionary's definition in English as *a sneaky, unexpected, or clever swap or exchange.* We'll see if somebody comes up with a good equivalent in French.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attesté en 1933 ([Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=switch)) avec le suffixe en [-eroo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-eroo) pour des trucs familiers et humoristiques. À l'image de ce qu'on a mentionné en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52153/whats-the-translation-of-switcheroo-in-french#comment108241_52153), [*Larousse en ligne anglais-français*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/switcheroo/1001487) donne « changement inattendu » mais ajoute dans le contexte de phrase *to pull a switcheroo* « surprendre tout le monde » ; on est loin de la qualification « US, very informal » qu'on lui donne. À mon avis on peut utiliser l'équivalent du *sleigh of hand* « (petit) tour de [passe-passe](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/passe-passe#b48968f485cf1ad9) » (*d'escamotage*), avec « [petit](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/petit) » mélioratif pour sortir du cadre normal de l'emploi et rendre ça sympatique, familier. Dans mon sociolecte je parlerais peut-être de « (faire une) [passe](https://oreilletendue.com/2011/03/19/faire-la-passe/) » mais il y a trop de sens distincts pour que ce soit clair et c'est normalement le gain monétaire...

Comment: Thanks,  passe-passe is a good idea.

Comment: Il n'est absolument pas question  dans le concept « switcheroo » de tour de passe-passe, d'escamotage, ou de quoi que ce soit de cette sorte.

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî Oui, bien sûr, pas besoin de moi, mais quand même, je fais remarquer ce qui est faux dans ce raisonnement, si raisonnement il y a.

Answer (score 0):

A faithfull enough translation is "*volte-face*".

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/volte-face)) **volte-face** B. − Au fig. Changement subit et total dans le comportement, les opinions d'une personne. Synon. pirouette, retournement, revirement, volte.Volte-face d'un gouvernement, d'un parti.

Comment: *Volte-face* works for people (directly or metaphorically) but not for objects.

Comment: @jlliagre Anyway, I have never heard "switcheroo" used for anything else than an act carried out by a person or a group of them.

Comment: Le registre ne convient pas et le terme ne peut être employé dans aucun des exemples de Wiktionary concernant _switcheroo_ : https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/switcheroo

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî Soit, le registre est courant en français, pas formel, ce qui rend le terme acceptable en tant que traduction. « Clever » n'a rien à voir avec « passe-passe » cependant.

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî Vrai, on n'appelle pas l'interchange des choses un volte-face, seulement la décision de faire le changement. « switcheroo » comprend plusieurs sens, ce  dernier n'est  pas couvert.

Comment: _Revirement de situation_ serait utile par ailleurs. Quant à la _substitution_, que tu peines à évoquer, possiblement aussi.

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî Oui, mais il manque cet élément de soudaineté et de surprise ; il semble essentiel, de plus que l'humour manque toujours.

Comment: Ça va prendre des adjectifs, une tournure etc. le mot unique n'est pas une panacée. En anglais ce n'est pas que le mot, qui est essentiellement _switch_, c'est le suffixe qui créé le ton.